# how 'temporary' must a variable be before it is considered 'throwaway'?

Tags: java, coding-style

The ['Naming convention' page at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java) contains the following statement under the Java conventions:

> One-character variable names should be avoided except for temporary "throwaway" variables.

How 'temporary' does a variable need to be before it is an acceptable candidate for a one-character name?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++, if you're asking about a Java naming convention? If you want to know what the authors of that naming convention meant, then check the sources on the wikipedia article. What *we* think is a "throwaway" variable might not be the same as  what the authors of the naming convention you're reading thought

Comment: because I am programming in C++. I was going to tag it "language-agnostic" but that is also problematic because I referring to something written about Java.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as an answer so I'm putting it in comment. But I use them for loop counters and then possibly x y and z if i am doing coordinates. Stuff like that.

Comment: I edited the tags. What you wrote reads as a question about how to interpret a specific Java naming convention. All the more general, and subjective, questions, like "how should I name my variables", or "how should I apply this Java naming convention to my C++ code" are impossible for us to answer because they're subjective, it's up to you and what you prefer. But a question of "how to interpret the naming convention described here" is objectively answerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use single-letter names in only a few circumstances:

- Coordinates such as `x` and `y`.
- Loop iteration using `for` where the variable is block scoped and named `i`, `j`, `k`, ...
- Generic type names, e.g., `E` for element, `K` for key, `V` for value, etc.

In all other cases I use longer names. Over time I find myself dropping shorter forms that I used to use. I rarely even abbreviate anymore. I can type fast, and real words are easier to type than abbreviations.

- `childCount`
- `titleNormalizer`
- `colorLoader`

This makes it a lot easier when I need to search for uses and modify the code a year later.

Comment: And with a nice IDE you don't even need to type all the name any more. Code completion certainly has changed my naming habits (for the better).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is going to be opinion based, but here are some considerations.

Index in a for loop or other thing that needs an index.  Small scope is important.  Besides for-loops I've also written code to complete a SQL statement like

```
int idx = 0;
ps.addInt(idx++, userId);
ps.addString(idx++, userName);
ps.addString(idx++, userEmail);
```

But even in that case I found `idx` preferable to `i`.  As a maintainer, `idx` tells me that the writer really meant index.  `i` tells me that the writer may have meant index, or may have been bad at naming variables and I have to read the code a bit more to disambiguate.

Of course, features like `foreach` have coped with the fact that this is rather boilerplate and the language shouldn't require throwaway variables, which I believe C++11 now supports.

Note that one-letter variables have the somewhat silly but rather relevant consideration of being hard to `grep` for, hard to search and replace, etc.  If you develop from an IDE this is less crucial but if there's even a chance you won't be, then this matters a bit more.  Even just `grep` to see where a variable is changed is harder if you use `i` instead of `ii`.

So those considerations said, my firm opinion is:

Never use one letter names.   At least make it two.  Only use them in places where all developers who code in that language know a throwaway is expected.  The only two examples I can think of are `for` loops and `rc` for return code in C.  In Java or C++11, if you find yourself using a one letter throwaway, design your code better, since there are language features meant to avoid this.

Comment: one character variables should be only used at a small local scope.. so the whole `grep` stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: No, it's not.  A "small local scope" can become bigger when your for loop expands.  Or if your loop becomes nested in an outer loop and you want to change `i` to `j`.  Or if you want to see everywhere in your code you could swap out a `for` for `foreach`.  Generally I prefer to begin a for loop like this with a reference though, like `Character& character = characters[ii];`

Comment: none of those ever happened to me.. maybe you violated your own rules of when a one character variable is acceptable?